# Compare Keys of more than 3 HashMaps

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap

I want to compare the keys of four hashmaps. All of the keys in the Hashmaps are equal. But I would like to evaluate each hashmap to compare the keys of all four hashmaps. In the code below, I am using 4 nested loops and then using a logical AND. If `true`, I want to add the Values to an Array List. Is this possible?

I have seen some code on the forum, but found nothing where we can compare 4 hashmaps. So do I need to add the Values to the ArrayList and not the Keys?

```
public static Map<String, Boolean> areEqualKeyValues(Map<String, String> firstMap, Map<String, String> secondMap,Map<String, String> thirdMap, Map<String, String> fourthMap) {

        ArrayList<String> reporValues = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> filteredMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : firstMap.entrySet()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : secondMap.entrySet()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry3 : thirdMap.entrySet()) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry4 : fourthMap.entrySet()) {
                            if (entry1.getKey().equals(entry2.getKey())
                                    && entry2.equals(entry3.getKey())
                                    && entry1.equals(entry3.getKey())
                                    && entry3.equals(entry4.getKey())) {
                                reporValues.add(entry1.getValue() + entry2.getValue() + entry3.getValue() + entry4.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                filteredMap.put(entry1.getKey(), reporValues.toString());
            }
```

Comment: No, your keys are not "ordered", because they are in a  java Set which is an unordered collection.

Comment: To get an answer, you have to define "compare" in "compare the keys of four hashmaps"

Comment: Sorry , I just rectified my question. I need to at the values to the ArrayList after comparing all the keys. So the KeySet approach will not work for, I just attempted it.

Comment: I can't find the return statement, what should this method return?

Comment: I only pasted the code up until the for loop, Initially i returned the filtered values.

Comment: Initially I returned the filtered values along with the result either true or false and returned a hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

1. The return type is wrong.
2. You need to compare a key with a key whereas you have compared some keys with the entry itself.
3. You haven't returned anything from the function.

Given below is the corrected function with a demo code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Test
        Map<String, String> firstMap = Map.of("a", "a1", "b", "b-first_", "c", "c1", "d", "d1");
        Map<String, String> secondMap = Map.of("x", "z1", "b", "b-second_", "y", "y1", "z", "z1");
        Map<String, String> thirdMap = Map.of("b", "b-third_", "m", "m1", "n", "n1");
        Map<String, String> fourthMap = Map.of("a", "a1", "p", "p1", "b", "b-fourth_");
        Map<String, String> filteredMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> reporValues = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(areEqualKeyValues(firstMap, secondMap, thirdMap, fourthMap, filteredMap, reporValues));
        System.out.println(filteredMap);
        System.out.println(reporValues);
    }

    public static boolean areEqualKeyValues(Map<String, String> firstMap, Map<String, String> secondMap,
            Map<String, String> thirdMap, Map<String, String> fourthMap, Map<String, String> filteredMap,
            List<String> reporValues) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : firstMap.entrySet()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : secondMap.entrySet()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry3 : thirdMap.entrySet()) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry4 : fourthMap.entrySet()) {
                        if (entry1.getKey().equals(entry2.getKey()) && entry2.getKey().equals(entry3.getKey())
                                && entry3.getKey().equals(entry4.getKey()) && entry4.getKey().equals(entry1.getKey())) {
                            reporValues
                                    .add(entry1.getValue() + entry2.getValue() + entry3.getValue() + entry4.getValue());
                            filteredMap.put(entry1.getKey(), reporValues.toString());
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
{b=[b-first_b-second_b-third_b-fourth_]}
[b-first_b-second_b-third_b-fourth_]
```

Comment: I will attempt this approach too. thanks @Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: I attempted this approach and it works too, thanks @Avind

Comment: @Riidonesh - You are most welcome. Thanks for confirming that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static Map<String, String> areEqualKeyValues(Map<String, String>... maps) {
    if (maps.length <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maps");
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map<String, String> map : maps)
        keys.addAll(map.keySet());
    Map<String, String> filteredMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : keys) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map<String, String> map : maps)
            sb.append(map.get(key));
        filteredMap.put(key, sb.toString());
    }
    return filteredMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I have attempted it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate over the `entrySet` but use the [`keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) instead.
Then you can just use the [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) of the first `keySet` repeatedly to only retain the objects that are in all the sets.

Comment: Sorry , I just rectified my question. I need to add the values of the hashmaps to the ArrayList after comparing all the keys. So the KeySet approach will not work for me unfortunately, I just attempted it with the Keyset, Is there perhaps another alternative?. – Riidonesh just now   Edit

Comment: @Riidonesh should not change much: the only difference is that you need an additional step after getting the combined keyset to retrieve the value from each map based on the key in the combined keyset

Comment: I retrieved the values I needed as per your second comment. it worked, I just need to refine it. thanks!